# How do I give cell values as parameters to ROW() formula in MS Excel?

Tags: excel

Giving static numerical values to the `ROW()` formula like `ROW($1:$2))` works perfectly (obviously), but I have both the values it requires in cells... Here what I am trying to build : `ROW($C3:$E4))`. This works, but gives me the value `3` (C3 cells's row).

What should I do in order to get the value inside C3 cell to pass it to ROW()?

Comment: Have you tried indirect() ?

Answer (score 1):

For Excel ***365***:

If we enter:

```
=ROW(7:13)
```

in **D1**, we get:

[image]

Now if **G1** contains *7* and **G2** contains *13*, then:

```
=ROW(INDIRECT(G1 & ":" & G2))
```

will give us the same result:

[image]

Comment: If OP needs numbers of rows then I think SEQUENCE() would be good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a **volatile** `INDIRECT` set-up when there exists a non-volatile alternative:

`=ROW(INDEX(A:A,G1):INDEX(A:A,G2))`

which is volatile only at workbook open.